# This code prints out math table of 3,4,5,6,7,8, How can i write short version of this code?

Tags: python

```
numbers = [i for i in range(1,11)]
def table(num):
    three = num * 3
    four =  num * 4
    five = num * 5
    six =  num * 6
    seven = num * 7
    eight = num * 8

    print(three,four,five,six,seven,eight)

answer = [i for i in numbers if table(i)]
```

This code looks a bit childish, Is there any way to create a short version of this code?

PS: This code works perfectly, i just want to know the short version of it.Thanks

this code prints the following output

```
3 4 5 6 7 8
6 8 10 12 14 16
9 12 15 18 21 24
12 16 20 24 28 32
15 20 25 30 35 40
18 24 30 36 42 48
21 28 35 42 49 56
24 32 40 48 56 64
27 36 45 54 63 72
30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: How do you intend to use those variables created inside the function, in the global scope?

Comment: This code doesn't even work...

Comment: @BillLynch this code works perfectly, i have updated  the question.

Comment: @Alex I apologise, this was my first question on stack overflow, I have updated the question. Please comment if you still this find question vague. Sorry again.

Comment: @RiteshYadav See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
for l in [[n * i for i in range(3, 9)] for n in range(1, 11)]:
    print(*l)
```

outputs

```
3 4 5 6 7 8
6 8 10 12 14 16
9 12 15 18 21 24
12 16 20 24 28 32
15 20 25 30 35 40
18 24 30 36 42 48
21 28 35 42 49 56
24 32 40 48 56 64
27 36 45 54 63 72
30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt the reply, could you please suggest me some good resources or tutorials on the for loop which you answered, so that i can learn more about this topic.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself writing repetitive code like that you should ask yourself:

> Can I use a loop instead?
>
> Can I do this recursively?
>
> Can I make another function to handle this repetitive task for me?

Here is a way you could tighten up your code with a loop:

```
def table(num):
  for i in range(3,9):
    print(num * i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work . Please see the question again, i have updated the question.